# Prevent change of one field in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, hobo

I have two related models - let's say `Activity` and `Step`. `Activity has_many :steps` and `Step belongs_to :activity` which means the table for `steps` has an `activity_id` column.

This is in Hobo 1.3, so Rails 3.0.

What I want is to ensure that *after `Step` creation* it is not possible to move a step to another `Activity`. We don't want the `activity_id` field to change.

I've removed the field from edit forms, but I'm looking for a stronger constraint. Essentially I want to validate on `update` (not on `create`) that the column isn't being touched. Hobo's documentation doesn't suggest anything of the sort inside Hobo, so I'm looking at [Rails validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html), but so far I haven't found the "only do this on update" constraint that I remember, nor a validation that something isn't changing.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can declare an attribute as read_only with `attr_readonly :your_field_name`.
But this won't create an error if you try to write this attribute, it will fail silently.
(This attribute will be ignored for all SQL-Updates)

Another option might be, to write a validation for this case, might look like this:

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :activity_id_not_changed

  private

  def activity_id_not_changed
    if activity_id_changed? && self.persisted?
      errors.add(:activity_id, "Change of activity_id not allowed!")
    end
  end
end
```

`persisted?` returns true, if this is not a new record and it is not destroyed.

Links:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-readonly_attributes

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F

Comment: `attr_readonly` works as advertised, but may be causing a wrinkle with another aspect of the app. I'll try the validation approach tomorrow and see if that does better.

Comment: If you really need to change the ID somewhere else in your application, you can do this even with the validation approach with following: `step.save(:validate => false)`

Comment: It's not a change issue elsewhere; it's an object copy. (So, say we hypothetically copied the `Activity` in a way that also copied all the `Steps`; for some reason that's not working, and I haven't yet burrowed deeply enough into the copy code to understand if this change broke it.)

Answer (score 20):

With validates inclusion:

```
  validates :activity_id,
            inclusion: { in: ->(i) { [i.activity_id_was] } },
            on: :update
```

No need for additional method.

Comment: This actually works quite well. It's not super clear what is happening so adding a comment for your colleagues and future self will help. Additionally, the default error message this generates isn't great (e.g. "activity_id is not included in the list") so I would recommend adding a `message` param inside the `inclusion` that says something like "cannot be changed after creation".

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this too with the Hobo permissions system: http://hobocentral.net/manual/permissions

For example:

```rb
def update_permitted?
  acting_user.administrator && !activity_id_changed?
end
```